# jQuery .attr() not working with WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site located at http://test.bcminiwarehouses.com

I am trying to add 2 attributes to the Make a Payment link in the menu so that it functions like clicking on the + on the top right.

When I inspect the element in Chrome and manually add the attributes, the link works as desired. However the jquery command appears not to be functioning to automatically add these attributes.

The code that can be viewed in the source code is:

```
$(".menu-item-6654").attr('data-target', '.x-widgetbar');
$(".menu-item-6654").attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a conflict between jQuery and Wordpress,try to do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".menu-item-6654").attr('data-target', '.x-widgetbar');
    $(".menu-item-6654").attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code in 
$(function() {

});

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not correct the issue.